# Is it possible to use Timestamps in pyomo for an index set?

Tags: python, timestamp, time-series, pyomo

As the title says, I'm trying to use pandas or numpy Timestamps for an index set in Pyomo, as this would make it very nice to add time-related constraints (for example the state at some time x might be related to the state in the previous hour).

I have a pandas time series and I'm creating the time index with

```
model.time_ind = pyo.Set(initialize=pandas_timeseries.index)
```

The model is for an electric vehicle that needs to be charged during at a certain time and where the state of charge in one hour is related to the state of charge in the previous hour and the charge rate during the previous hour.

```
model.charge = pyo.Var(model.time_ind, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.stateOfCharge = pyo.Var(model.time_ind, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

def stateOfChargeRule(model, time):         
    if time == pandas_timeseries.index[0]:  # set initial charges
        return model.stateOfCharge[time] == soc_init
    prev_hour = time - pd.Timedelta('1 hour', freq='H') # relate charging to previous hour
    return model.stateOfCharge[time] == model.stateOfCharge[prev_hour] + model.charge[prev_hour]                         


model.SOCconstraint = pyo.Constraint(model.time_ind, rule=stateOfChargeRule)
```

it seems to work fine as long as I am only looping over this index, but it's not working when I try to bring in the time delta.

I am getting this error message:

IndexError:
    only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and
    integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

So why can I loop over the index, but not use a timestamp to index directly?

Comment: It's hard to tell what is causing the issue without seeing the variable and constraint definition(s). Could you include those as well?

Comment: Sure, I updated it!

Comment: Could you also share the full error message printout?